# New output cell generated for each run of a GraphicsGrid - is there a way to simply update the same output cell each run?

Tags: plotting, programming

I have a Code cell that generates a set of plots in a GraphicsGrid[].  Each time I execute the Code cell, a new Output cell is generated.

Is there a way to simply update a single output cell instead of generating a new one?

Comment: Stackexchange etiquette: If an answer solved your problem, you should consider accepting the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notebook may have the option `OutputAutoOverwrite` set to False, or the output cell below your input has the setting `CellAutoOverwrite->False`. You can use the Option Inspector in the Format menu to set this option.

Comment: Sjoerd - Thank you very much for your note.  In my case the Outputoverwrite and CellAutoOverwrite properties are readonly and cannot be changed (not sure why)..

Comment: @user1585715 You should probably be able to remove that cell property too. If I remember correctly the context menu should have that option.